# Session Management (Zend Framework specific)

Tags: zend-framework, session, remember-me

I'm trying to get the **rememberMe()** function to remember users and retain sessions for months at a time.

I've read that if you pass a value through **rememberMe()** it will not work if the session has already been started. From the **session_set_cookie_params()** documentation in the PHP manual, "you need to call **session_set_cookie_params()** for every request and before **session_start()** is called."

By I am calling **Zend_session::start()** in my bootstrap as i thought I was supposed to. My problem is that **rememberMe()** doesn't seem to be working.

When I call **session_get_cookie_params();** I get:

```
Array([lifetime] => 0 [path] => / [domain] => [secure] => httponly] =>)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem. sessions were being erased by another website on the same server which expires sessions every 24 minutes. To fix this I set the session.save_path to a new folder. I also set session.gc_maxlifetime and session.cookie_lifetime to be very large numbers.

problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the start() method. It should work fine if you are using MVC. The session_start must be called before any output is send and that's right before sending response (because of outputbuffering). The session is started automatically upon first Zend_Session_namespace usage.